# How to show that F is recursive?

Tags: first-order-logic, recursion, incompleteness

In the road to Godel's incompleteness theorem, Problem saying:

Show that Frame For $G:\omega\times\omega\times\omega^{n}\rightarrow\omega$
  a recursive function, the function $F:\omega\times\omega^{n}\rightarrow\omega$
 , given by

$ F(a,\bar{b})=G(\bar{F}(a,\bar{b}),a,\bar{b})$
 is recursive.

And solution begins with

$H(a,\bar{b})=\mu x(Seq(x)\wedge lh(x)=a\wedge\forall i<a((x)_{i+1}=G(Init(x,i),i,\bar{b}))$

I tried to show it by using definitions. So,

$F(a,\bar b)=G(\bar F(a,\bar b),a,\bar b)=G(<F(0,\bar b),\cdots ,F(a-1,\bar b)>,a,\bar b)=G(\mu x(lh(x)=a\wedge (x)_1 =F(0,\bar b)\wedge \cdots \wedge(x)_a=F(a-1,\bar b),a,b)$

I'm totally lost. How do I get that equation?

*) Seq(x) is a relation x is a sequence number for some sequence and Init is a initial sequence function

**) Definition of $\bar F$  is given a function $F:\omega\times \omega^k\rightarrow \omega$. a function  from $\omega \times \omega^k$ to $\omega$ given by 
$\bar F(a,\bar b)=<F(0,\bar b),\dots , F(a-1),\bar b)>$, 
that is, $\mu x(lh(x)=a\wedge\forall i<a((x)_{i+1} =F(i,\bar b))).$

Comment: What does the overbar notation mean here?

Comment: @HenningMakholm overbar is an element of $\omega ^n$

Comment: What does $\bar F$ mean, specifically? And is it on purpose that the formula after "defined by" seems to consist of two identical halves squashed together? Are there some minus-ones missing somewhere, which would make those halves into a meaningful recursion relation?

Comment: You'll probably have to disclose the definition of "recursive function" that you're working with. There are several ones in circulation, not all of them equivalent. (In particular Gödel himself in the 1931 paper used "recursive" for what is today more often called "primitive recursive").

Comment: I had a mistake while I translate problems written in  LyX into this site.  I fixed question.

Comment: I use the term 'recursive' as a set or relation such that if it is a relation its characteristic function can be given by its membership, and if it is a function, it obtained by finitely many applications of composition or minimization to projection function, +, or characteristic of <

Comment: I still don't understand what $\bar F$ means ... and by extension how your definition of $F$ works. I'm wondering whether it's all some kind of typo for $$ F(a+1,\bar b) = G(F(a,\bar b), a, \bar b) \\ F(0,\bar b) = K(\bar b) $$ that is, the usual primitive recursion scheme; but then it would be strange that you're not mentioning a base case $K$ at all. On the other hand, even if $\bar F$ was supposed to be $F$, you seem to be defining $F(a,\bar b)$ as the solution to $x=G(x,a,\bar b)$, but this won't always have a solution! So I'm confused.

Comment: I added the definition of that function.

Comment: Okay, with the edits I think I understand what you're asking. Unfortunately I'm not used to working with just minimization (but no primitive recursion or even multiplication) as the basic workhorse concept, so I'm not sure how one would prove it with those definitions. Let's hope someone more knowledgeable comes by.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. It really helps my question more easier